# Transform data before and after storage in EF database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a List that is serialized into an SQL database.  I am using EntityFramework, and it would be great if there is a way in the model to be able to have a way of extracting the field (stored as a varchar(MAX) - serialized base64) and deserializing into the List.  And then, when saving, I want to be able to have it automatically serialize.

I am using EF Model First.

```
public string HostList { get; set; }
```

The above sample is what I want my hostlist to be.  It should be a List, and is stored currently in the database as varchar(MAX).  I was thinking of XML serialization etc and storing as xml, but that doesnt help with returning the format I want.

Comment: Your question is very un clear.

Comment: All I am looking for is a way for me to get a List<IPAddress> _automatically_ from my database, without having to call extra functions to deserialize.

Comment: You'll have to wrap it up if you want it 'automatically'. Get your list and serialise it to xml.

Comment: But is there a way, even if I serialize to XML, that HostList will return List<IPAddress>, rather than me having to call a deserialize method.  So when EF saves, it will save as xml, but I want to be able to access the property as a list<ipaddress>

Answer (score 0):

You could write a list class that is serializable to a string.

**Not tested** example:

```
public class AddressList : IList<IPAdress>
{
    public string Serialized { get; private set; }

    private List<IPAddress> _innerList = new List<IPAddress>();

    //To be informed when the list is modified.
    public event EventHandler OnModified;

    public AddressList(string serializedString)
    {
        //Init the collection from the serialized string
    }

    public void Add(IPAdress item)
    {
        _innerList.Add(item)

        //Update the serialized string
        UpdateString();
    }

    public void Remove(IPAdress item)
    {
        _innerList.Remove(item);

        //Update the serialized string
        UpdateString();
    }

    private void UpdateString()
    {
        //Do your update job.

        //Call the event.
        if (OnModified != null)
            OnModified(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    //Rest of IList implementation....
}
```

Then in your Entity :

```
public partial class MyEntity
{
    private AddressList _addresses;

    public IList<IPAdress> Adresses
    {
        get
        {
            if (_addresses == null)
            {
                _addresses = new AddressList(HostList);
                //When the list is modified, you want to update your property.
                _addresses.OnModified += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    HostList = ((AddressList) sender).Serialized;
                };
            }
            return _adresses;
        }
    }
}
```

This way, when you add/remove items from your list, the string is "automatically" updated.